# Using same VkPipeline with more than one VkRenderPass

Tags: vulkan

`VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo`  expects assignment of a  `VkRenderPass`   to `.renderPass` property. I don't really understand why a pipeline must be coupled with render pass. I mean, `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo` doesn't directly "talks" to render pass related content, like FBOs and their attachments. I may want to use same pipeline with more than one render pass, like in case where I want to render same set of objects in different scenes, so do I have to create another one with exactly the same setup?

Just to add that creating `VkPipeline` with `.renderPass = nullptr` fails with validation error:

> vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: required parameter
>   pCreateInfos[0].renderPass specified as VK_NULL_HANDLE.Invalid
>   VkRenderPass Object 0x0. The Vulkan spec states: renderPass must be a
>   valid VkRenderPass handle
>   (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-renderPass-parameter)

Comment: "*I may want to use same pipeline with more than one render pass, like in case where I want to render same set of objects in different scenes*" Why would that involve using a different renderpass?

Comment: In my use case I may have several scenes with different render targets,different dimensions of the render targets,and MSAA enabled/ disabled

Comment: Aside from the sample counts, none of those things affect the structure of the `VkRenderPass` object that gets used. And as far as multisampling is concerned... well, stop doing that. Pick a sample count and stick with it.

Comment: @NicolBolas what do you mean by " pick a sample count and stick with it" ?

Comment: It means to pick a sample count and stick with it. To not have a bunch of different render targets with different sample counts. I can see the need for doing multisampling for the main rendering process while not doing multisampling for reflections processed via render-to-texture. But that's just two sample counts, which requires two render passes and two pipelines.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's not what I mean. In my case some render passes have MSAA,others don't.

Comment: But that's *exactly* what I said. To "have MSAA" means you have a sample count other than 1. You shouldn't need more than two separate sample counts, so you should just have one pipeline for each sample count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo` doesn't directly "talks" to render pass related content, like FBOs and their attachments.

Of course it does. What do you think a fragment shader is doing when it writes into a render pass' attachments?

> Do I have to create another one with exactly the same setup?

No. As per the specification:

*"`renderPass` is a handle to a render pass object describing the environment in which the pipeline will be used; the pipeline must only be used with an instance of any render pass compatible with the one provided. See Render Pass Compatibility for more information".*

... so a pipeline can be used with any render pass that is compatible with the one used to create it.